# NMR Assignment of cinnamaldehyde

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

I'm struggling to understand the assignment of the aromatic protons in this compound. Based on the simulated spectra (and lit spectra), the three protons on the left are all overlapping. To the best of my knowledge, you can draw resonance structures with both carbocations or carbanions at the ortho and para positions, so I don't quite get why the meta protons will end up with nearly identical shifts as there's no similar resonance effect (unless I'm missing it).

[image: Cinnamaldehyde Structure and Spectra]

Comment: The spectrum belongs to the actual compound and the checmical shifts depend on local electron density distribution. The ionic resonance structures you can draw are far from reality, unless the aromatic system breaks up, i.e. in a reaction. Why do you expect the distortion of the aromatic ring system by the substituent to be very strong?

Comment: Because the electron density distribution can be approximated via resonance structure and chemical shifts can be estimated based on the ortho/meta/para directing nature of substituents as described in every modern organic chemistry textbook.

Comment: Drawing resonance structures does *not* give you any quantitative information how strong the effect on the electron distribution and therefore chemical shift will be. ?! And of course the ortho/meta/para directing nature of substituents correlates somewhat with the chemical shifts increments, but one is at least partially a property of the sigma complex , the other a property of the undisturbed aromatic ring. Pears and apples ... ;)

Comment: The system of chemical shift increments is very well worked out (since many decades), and the prediction you get is very likely correct (you mention yourself that literature values agree with it). So obviously the attempt to explain the CS with the resonance structures doesn't carry very far. If modern books (which?) recommend that, phooi.